# How to add new parameters to my URL - Laravel?

Tags: html, laravel

I need your help. So, I need to add more details on my URL. But what I did doesn't working. I need to add `id` of news on my link. Now, my link is like that : `www.website.com/news/my-news-title`, but it should be like that : `www.website.com/news/88/my-news-title`.

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('news/{id}/{slug}', 'ModelController@newsSingle');
```

Here is my view link:

```
   <a href="{{ url('news') }}/{{ $news->id }}/{{ $news->slug }}"></a>
```

Here is my controller:

```
 public function newsSingle($slug, $id)

    {

        // return $slug;

        $data = $this->data;

        $data['news'] = News::with('category_name','news_image','models','creative')->where('slug','=',$slug)->orWhere('id','=',$id)->first();

        if(count($data['news']) == 0)
        {
            abort(404);
        }

        updatNewsView($data['news']['id']);

        // $displayitem = DisplayItem::where('slug','=',url('news'))->first();

        // $data['page'] = $displayitem;

        $data['title'] = $data['news']->title;

        $data['breadcrumb'] = $data['news']->title;

        // $data['menu'] = $tag->title;

        $data['metadescription'] = $data['news']->metadescription;

        $data['metatitle'] = $data['news']->metatitle;

        // $data['blogs'] = $tag->blog;

        return view('news.single_news',$data);

    }
```

Now, the link is good, but when I'm trying to access it I get `404 error` .

Comment: did you check that `{{ $news->id }}` returns the id ? how are you getting the `$news` object with which you build the link ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/urls#urls-for-named-routes

Comment: @N69S yes, it returns me the id.

Comment: @TsaiKoga i'm using laravel 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your params are switched around in your controller. You have `id/slug` in your route but `$slug, $id` in your controller action.

Changing the following should work:

Controller:

```
public function newsSingle($id, $slug)
```

View:

```
<a href="{{ url('news') . "/{$news->id}/{$news->slug}" }}"></a>
```

Or use the named routes from mrhn's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your Url generation seems wrong, usually you would do named routes.

```
Route::get('news/{id}/{slug}', 'ModelController@newsSingle')->name('news');
```

Generate your url like this in the blade, by using the route helper that will return the url.

```
<a href="{{ route('news', $news->id, $news->slug) }}"></a>
```

Comment: hello, I tried it but doesn't working. I'm using laravel 5.2, is that a problem ? I just get `undefined variable` for `id` and `slug.`

Comment: had not closed the route call, remember to understand the code and not just paste it in :)

Comment: Thanks, I solve it. Sorry, I'm just tired and I can miss some things :)